# For loop starts adding more elements halfway?

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, append

I have created a GUI and have several parameters which changes. Hence I need to add/remove numbers from a matrix.

The problem is that the loop runs fine until a certain point (here, where j= 2). Then it starts adding 2 elements instead of 1. What happens?

I want HIGH and LOW to be size of NS*PARTS.
Please help:) 
PS: I tried to make the code minimal and still give all the information needed, hence please let me know if there is something I did not add in and I will add it!

```py
        #-------------------- CHANGE CONNECTIONS ACCORDING TO NEW VALUES ----------------------
        print ('PARTS: ' + str(self.PARTS))
        print ('oldnrofPARTS: ' + str(oldnrofPARTS))
        print ('NS: ' + str(self.NS))
        print ('NM: ' + str(self.NM))
        print ('CONS: ' + str(self.CONS))
        print ('HIGH: ' + str(self.HIGH))
        print ('LOW: ' + str(self.LOW))
        high = '0'.zfill(int(self.AW/4))
        self.AW = 32

        if (self.PARTS>oldnrofPARTS):
            for j in range(self.NS):
                for i in range(self.NM):
                    # for m in range(self.PARTS-oldnrofPARTS):
                    while(len(self.CONS[j][i])<self.PARTS):
                        self.CONS[j][i].append(True)

                while(len(self.HIGH[j])<self.PARTS):
                    self.HIGH[j].append(high)
                    self.LOW[j].append(high)
                    print('line 87 HIGH: ' + str(self.HIGH))

        elif (oldnrofPARTS>self.PARTS):
            for j in range(self.NS):
                for m in range(self.NM):
                    while(len(self.CONS[j][m])>self.PARTS):
                            self.CONS[j][m].pop(self.PARTS)
                while(len(self.HIGH[j])>self.PARTS):
                    self.HIGH[j].pop(self.PARTS)
                    self.LOW[j].pop(self.PARTS)
                    print('line 97 HIGH: ' + str(self.HIGH))

        print ('PARTS: ' + str(self.PARTS))
        print ('oldnrofPARTS: ' + str(oldnrofPARTS))
        print ('NS: ' + str(self.NS))
        print ('NM: ' + str(self.NM))
        print ('CONS: ' + str(self.CONS))
        print ('HIGH: ' + str(self.HIGH))
        print ('LOW: ' + str(self.LOW))
```

This is the result I get

```py
PARTS: 3
oldnrofPARTS: 2
NS: 4
NM: 4
CONS: [[[True, True], [True, True], [True, True], [True, True]], [[True, True], [True, True], [True, True], [True, True]], [[True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True]], [[True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True]]]
HIGH: [['00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000']]
LOW: [['00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000']]
line 87 HIGH: [['00000000', '00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000']]
line 87 HIGH: [['00000000', '00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000']]
line 87 HIGH: [['00000000', '00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000', '00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000', '00000000', '00000000']]
PARTS: 3
oldnrofPARTS: 2
NS: 4
NM: 4
CONS: [[[True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True]], [[True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True]], [[True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True]], [[True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True], [True, True, True]]]
HIGH: [['00000000', '00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000', '00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000', '00000000', '00000000']]
LOW: [['00000000', '00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000', '00000000', '00000000'], ['00000000', '00000000', '00000000', '00000000']]
```

Comment: use `print()` in different places to see values in variables - it can help to see problem. OR learn how to use debugger.

Comment: Please change `self.HIGH[j].append(high)` to `self.HIGH[j].append(j)` to see what parts of the loop actually do appending. My guess would be some reference points to the same list and that makes something append twice. If you look at `line 87 HIGH` prints, last line changes 3rd and 4th elements both at once! But it's hard for me to say more just by looking at 0s and punctuation

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix it by changing the way I added the elements, and by doing
```python
self.HIGH[j].append('0'.zfill(int(self.AW/4)))
self.LOW[j].append('0'.zfill(int(self.AW/4)))
```
instead!